# How do I define a range from the current position to the end of the file in an ex command?

Tags: substitute, ex-mode

I have a common routine where I need to do a text substitution from the current cursor position to the end of the file. I currently count how many lines there are until the end of the file and enter it manually:

```
:.,.25s/old/new/
```

Is there something I can enter instead of the `.25` to make the substitution apply from the current cursor position until the end of the file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is. For last line of a file, the address is `$`:

```
:.,$s/old/new/
```

See [`:help {address}`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%7Baddress%7D) for a fill list of possible addresses.